# Python parse list and list of tuples into csv

Tags: python

it's really frustrating: I just stored some data rows containing lists after a long long calculation in a csv file.
I am unable to get the csv data back into variable. 
Its more precise a row like

> pete; [1,2,3,4,5]; [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),...]

Sure, Python csv parses to a string :/, 
thus, if I try the list()-casting, it's like:

```
list("[(1,2),(3,4)]") = ['[','(','1',',',...]
```

Do you have any idea to cope with this?

thought I could use:

for name,list,lTuples in csvfile:

...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Huh? Sorry, I don't understand the question. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: If you just joined values together with a comma (eg: `','.join(stuff)`), when you saved the csv file, then the strings are not properly quoted and will require some creative parsing to reverse this encoding.

Comment: IIUC you're going to want `ast.literal_eval`, but the quoting issue that @AdamWagner pointed out is going to be a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: thankfully I used semicolons ...

Comment: Also, it sounds like you want a proper encoding (like json or pickle) instead of csv.  If it's not too late, I'd consider changing the format you're saving these calculations to.

Comment: You can get further with your csv parsing by specifying the delimiter.  `csv.reader(open('eggs.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=';')`.  But you will then still have to turn columns into lists and tuples. etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) (as long as the string contains only strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None).

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[(1,2),(3,4)]")
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: What's the difference between `ast.literal_eval` and the built-in `eval`?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is safe. Using the built-in `eval` on a string could be dangerous if it includes malicious code

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked for me! Answers, fast as lightning :)